# TSQL Join Query with count

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 tables I am joining to get some stats for a tool. I need to combine both of them to be able to get a count on the number of results that both tables will hold.

Below is the structure.

```
Table A

Account, tag


123, dog
456, cat,
123, pig
456, mouse
333, dog




Table B

tag, totalSearches

dog, 10
cat, 2
pig, 4
mouse, 4
```

Expected Result

```
Tag, Total Accounts Tag is On, Total Times Searched


dog, 2 , 10
cat, 1, 2
pig, 1, 4
mouse, 1, 4
```

I am just a little unsure on how to join the tables while also getting the count on the numbers of results that it finds.

Answer (score 0):

You can have result using this SQL:

```
SELECT 
  TA.TAG AS Tag, 
  COUNT(TA.Account) AS TotalAccountsTagIsOn,
  MAX(TB.totalSearches) AS TotalTimesSearched
FROM 
  TableA AS TA 
  INNER JOIN TableB AS TB ON 
    (TA.Tag = TB.Tag)
GROUP BY 
  TA.TAG;
```

You `JOIN` (connect) `Table A` and `Table B` using `Tag` column. You then `GROUP BY` `Tag`.
And `COUNT` Accounts and `MAX` totalSearches, because you have more than 1 row for each `Tag` in `Table A`.